# Showing unique values in a column along with another value associated with each

Tags: excel

I have an Excel table containing transactions of companies. It looks like this:

```
Customer    Phone   Item    Price
==================================
Company1            
Company2            
Company1            
Company3            
Company1
```

**I need to *see* the unique values of customer column.**

The result I want is:

```
Customer    Phone   Item    Price
==================================
Company1            
Company2            
Company3
```

Here is what I tried already:

- **Remove duplicates:**  To just get the unique values, I can use the remove duplicates of excel. However, since this is something I will be doing frequently, I would rather not have to make a copy of the table each time in order to delete duplicates.
- **Pivot table:** A pivot table does this job perfectly. My problem here is that I need other column info as well (e.g., the phone number) which I want to appear in the column next to the company. [I haven't yet figured out how to do this in a pivot table (i.e., to show a value as text instead of sum or count etc.)] - This would be the best option for me.

Comment: What about making a macro for removing duplicates? you can assign a shortcut and just press it whenever you like to repopulate your list.

Comment: @pnuts - I need to have it on the same row as the contact name

Comment: @Balinti - Sounds like a plan, to have the macro hide the duplicate rows and when I'm done to reshow them. (Although I was trying to stay away from macros since I want to keep it an xslx file because quickbooks cant read xlsm, and this excel file is for my work with quickbooks)

Comment: @pnuts - Awesome! I never knew about that!! This exactly what I wanted - best solution!! - Thanks! (I would mark this as correct answer...)

Comment: @pnuts - ☺  ☹ - Thanks a lot!

Comment: Something else, I usually turn off subtotals if using a pivot table in tabular form... reduces clutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't have a super long table where the recalculation will kill you, you could just add a calculated column like this and then filter on value being 1:

=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:B2,"=" & B3) > 0,0,1)

[image]

If recalculation is an issue, you can use the same or similar method with VBA except paste static values.

PivotTables are well suited for this kind of stuff, so that'd be my first go-to, but PivotTables are also frustratingly difficult to adapt to uses beyond their envisioned use... so there's a steep decline in their usefulness as you stray from that.

Ultimately, you may want to consider a relational database paradigm, and/or using Access.  That's one step up the sophistication ladder towards managing the kind of data you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried a few formulas.... but couldnt get it to work! - Mainly, I tried exactly what you wrote, but I didnt have the idea to limit the lookup to the row before the current cell!!! - Thanks!